# Jquery - get table header value from a row that has a field with a specific value, from a button click event

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, html-table, tableheader

I am using a horizontal table with a select list (dropdown) as one of the fields. When I click submit I need to grab the table header value for that column and the value from the dropdown.

My table `class = "views-table"` essentially looks like this:

```
header1 | header2 | header3 | header 4
--------------------------------------
select    select    select   select
data1     data2     data3    data4 

[submit button]
```

My dropdown `class="request-select"` element holds the following values:

```
select list:
  -empty
  -FIRST
  -SECOND
```

So after a user selects a first value the table should look like this:

```
header1 | header2 | header3 | header 4
--------------------------------------
select    FIRST    select   select
data1     data2     data3    data4 

[submit button]
```

And the data I am expecting after the user clicks submit is: `header2` and `FIRST`

I can grab the table header value from the `change` event from the dropdown with:

```
jQuery('table.views-table').on('change', 'td', function(e) {  
    var tableHead= e.delegateTarget.tHead.rows[0].cells[this.cellIndex];
    alert([jQuery(tableHead).text()]);  
    // returns `header2` from dropdown with `FIRST` value selected
});
```

But I can't figure out how to drill down and access this data from the submit button. I don't want to use a hidden element or use localstorage. Any ideas on how I should approach this? I am very inexperienced with jQuery. If you need more information please let me know and I can provide more details if needed.

Answer (score 0):

One of the approach would be providing related IDs to your headers and select tags. For example you can provide IDs like "select-1", "select-2"... to your dropdowns. Similarly you have to provide IDs to your header tags like "thead-1", "thead-2"..., Now on submit click event, check which dropdown value has been changed(value!="") and then grab the last digit of that dropdown ID. Now you can use that digit to get value of respected header.

Answer (score 0):

If you're able to get a handle on the cells index, then you can gets its value by using .val(), not .text().